# Can't find error in JS code

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a "bubble generator" that is mostly working, but is not properly clearing the bubbles and I can't figure out why.  Been staring at this for a while now.  Specifically, some of the bubbles are getting "cleared" as they float up, others aren't, and I can't see why.  ARGH!

http://jsfiddle.net/Dud2q/7/  (slowed waaay down so that you can easily watch a single bubble)

Logic flow (this just describes the code in the fiddle):

1. Create an imageData array (long list of pixels)

   ```
   imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
   ```
2. push new random bubbles onto the beginning of the "bubbles array" which draws bottom-up:

   ```
   for(var i=0, l=generators.length; i<l; i++){
       for(var j=0, m=0|Math.random()*6; j<m; j++){
           newBubbles.push( 0|generators[i] + j );
       }
       generators[i] = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, generators[i] + Math.random()*10 - 5));
   }
   bubbles.unshift(newBubbles);
   ```
3. loop all bubbles to be drawn and:

   1. clear the bubbles that were drawn in the last loop by setting alpha channel to 0 (transparent):

      ```
      if(i<(l-1)){
          x = 0|bubbles[i+1][j];
          offset = y * w * 4 + x * 4;
          pixels[offset+3] = 0;
      }
      ```
   2. draw new bubbles (`offset+1` = g, `offset+2` = b, `offset+3` = alpha):

      ```
      x = 0|(bubbles[i][j] += Math.random() * 6 - 3);
      offset = y * w * 4 + x * 4;
      pixels[offset+1] = 0x66;
      pixels[offset+2] = 0x99;
      pixels[offset+3] = 0xFF;
      ```

Comment: kind of hard to understand how it works. but maybe you can add a lifetime property that is randomly assigned

Comment: It's supposed to basically draw a bubble, bump it up one level, erase where it was and then draw it in the new position.  It's this erase that is broken, somewhere.... I think.  A lifetime wouldn't really help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the number of generators to a higher number seems to make it work.

Eg. `50..times(createBubbleGenerator);` almost works.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Not quite a solution, but I was looking into the same thing.  The actual issue is that I was looping the current array of bubbles and "assuming" that the previous array had the same number of bubbles in it.  That's not the case, so two different loops are needed.  The reason this "almost" works is that only the last few bubbles break, all the ones before that work (e.g. if one row had 200 bubbles and the next 190, only 10 bubbles would "break").  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dud2q/27/

Comment: Yes, changing the number of generators is more of a hack than the real solution. I noticed that the code was assuming the same thing you mentioned now. Glad you found the solution. :) It's a really nice piece of code to play with.

Comment: thanks :)  If you're the person creating dozens of updates, you know you can run a fiddle without updating it by clicking "Run" :)

Comment: Often I used 'Run', and was probably playing around with 'Update' too. ;)